# Will I be qualified for data science roles with a PhD in Engineering and Machine Learning?

Tags: career

Currently doing a funded PhD in Civil Engineering using Machine learning applications. In essence data driven modelling of a niche area of engineering (to do with some material deformation predictions etc.)

I have a years experience working as a Civil Engineer on site, and have a first class MEng in Civil & Structural Engineering.

I think I would really enjoy data science, and I am wondering if my PhD will provide a good stepping stone for this? And if so, what are some other things I can do to really make myself stand out as a data scientist?

Comment: You can participate in DS contests, like https://www.kaggle.com/, publish your private projects at Github, etc. All in all, prove your record.

Answer (score 1):

Write blogs, papers, and so on. Take part in the open source community. This PhD does neither qualify you nor not. But when you are able to show your passion you have got a ticket.